# SOLR refuses to bring exact matches, How?

Tags: solr, solr-schema

I have the following field type (notice no filters, no tokenizers)

```
<fieldType name="text_names" class="solr.StrField" />
```

I create a field in my schema using that type:

```
<field name="exact_type" type="text_names" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

now, I search `q=*:*&fq=exact_type:aa&fl=exact_type`
I still get results which have other than 'aa' in the `exact_type` field.
What am I missing here?

Also this behaves the same:

```
q=exact_type:aa&fl=exact_type
```

Comment: That looks to be the correct form to me. The only difference I have in a similar config is `sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"` on the `fieldType` and `omitNorms="true"` on the `field`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think that "q=*:*" works with DisMaxHandler and I believe that you are using it ,the correct syntax for both the queries should be:

```
q=&fq=exact_type:aa&fl=exact_type

fq=exact_type:aa&fl=exact_type
```